# Converting ascii to char

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following snippet

```
std::string encodedstr;
if(std::isdigit(encodedstr.at(i))) {
             num_of_times = encodedstr.at(i);
             std::cout << num_of_times << "\n";
         }
```

The output is :

```
52
51
```

I tried to cast it to a char but the output didn't change

```
num_of_times = static_cast<char>(encodedstr.at(i));
```

I am on windows with mingw64 compiler

Expected output:

```
4
3
```

How can i ensure cast `num_of_times` so that `num_of_times` contains expected output above.

My full code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/PuaW95Vw)

Comment: `num_of_times` is presumably an `int`. Your char gets cast right back to `int` when assigned to an `int` variable. Cast where you print, not where you assign.

Comment: If what you have is "`std::string encodedstr;
if(std::isdigit(encodedstr.at(i))) {`" - then `encodedstr` is an empty string and whatever `i` is is causing `.at()` to index out of bounds. So *clearly* that is *not* the code you have (or you would presumably have fixed that issue long ago) - so, could you please post a [mcve] with your *real* code?

Comment: @JesperJuhl its not full code but i am just need proper casting of a variable here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stead of `num_of_times = static_cast<char>(encodedstr.at(i));`

Use:

```
num_of_times = static_cast<char>(encodedstr.at(i)) - '0';
```

Check it out [here](https://ideone.com/58xrtc) for your original code.

ASCII value of `0` is `48`. So when you substitute `48` from any ASCII value of digit(0 - 9), say, from number `4` which is having ASCII value of `52`, we will get that exact decimal value, in our case `52-48 = 4`.

I guess, now this is clear to you.

*Output:*

```
Input string : AAAABBBAC111c
Encoded string : A4B3AC13c
4
3
1
3
Decoded string : AAAAABBBCCC
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help...if you check my full code you will notice that i use `num_of_times` in  a loop

Comment: yes, it's inside a loop, then what's the problem?

Comment: The loop is happening for too many times.It should be the same amount as the expected output in the post indicating issue with casting

Comment: @user2650277 Ow, sorry. Now, I've understood. Check it out whether this solves your issue or not.